# Fragment shader code from file doesn't work like hardcoded

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

At the shader loading stage I decided to load sources from a file instead of a hardcoded. Everything is loaded successfully, there are no errors at the shader assembly stage, but the color is not applied, only white. If I use hardcoded version, there's no problem and I see different color.

Problem triangle:

[image]

For example:

I've created a shader and applying source that I get from file. After that I need to cast from `std::string` to `const GLchar*` like `glShaderSource` need.

```cpp
GLuint fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

std::string fragShaderStr = getShaderSourceFromFile("fragment.glsl");
const GLchar *fragmentShaderSrc = fragShaderStr.c_str();

glShaderSource(fragmentShader, 1, &fragmentShaderSrc, nullptr);
glCompileShader(fragmentShader);
```

Listing of `getShaderSourceFromFile()`

```cpp
std::string getShaderSourceFromFile(std::string filename)
{
    std::string result;
    std::ifstream file(filename, std::ios::in);

    std::string line;
    while(!file.eof())
    {
        std::getline(file, line);
        result += line + '\n';
    }

    file.close();

    return result;
}
```

Listing of fragment shader

```c
#version 330 core

out vec4 color;

void main()
{
    color = vec4(1.0f, 0.5f, 0.2f, 1.0f);
}
```

In the end I check that attaching and linking of shaders to program is successfuly and I have no any errors

```cpp
GLuint shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();

glAttachShader(shaderProgram,vertexShader);
glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);

glGetProgramiv(shaderProgram, GL_LINK_STATUS, &success);

if (success == 0)
{
    glGetProgramInfoLog(shaderProgram, 512, nullptr, infoLog);
    std::cout << "[Shader Program Link] Error: " << infoLog << std::endl;
}
glDeleteShader(vertexShader);
glDeleteShader(fragmentShader);
```

I see that it's a char casting problem (maybe), but I don't understand how to fix it

Comment: Edit in a [mcve]; feel free to use [this](https://github.com/genpfault/glfw-mcve-base/blob/master/src/main.cpp) as a base.  For that MCVE make sure to use something like [`xxd -include`](https://manpages.debian.org/bookworm/xxd/xxd.1.en.html) to convert `fragment.glsl` into a static array; for all we know it has something weird in it like a BOM or UTF-16.

Comment: It's fixed by renaming shader files with ".vert" and ".frag" extensions instead of ".glsl". I thought that it doesn't matter

Comment: Please don't add answers to the question, post an answer instead.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in file reading mode. In my case I should open file in binary mode instead of `std::ios::in`

So, the function for shader reading is:

```cpp
std::string getShaderSourceFromFile(std::string filename)
{
    std::string result;
    std::ifstream file(filename, std::ios::binary);

    std::string line;
    while(!file.eof())
    {
        std::getline(file, line);
        result += line + '\n';
    }

    file.close();

    return result;
}
```